# Caching a JNI varaible in Java

Tags: java, caching, java-native-interface

I am creating a Java server code that need to call native methods written by C. The C file will return values to Java. Now I need cache the values and also make it thread-safety as the server code support multiple threads. Static variable doesn't work to me as its value is shared by the threads. So how can I achieve it? Thanks.

Comment: So why not cache and add thread-safety guards (eg. synchronized) on the Java side? How does JNI fit in at all?

Comment: Don't cache it. Keep it *once* where it will be most frequently accessed: *either* in the Java code *or* the JNI code. Not both. And use JNI to get the value from the layer where it's kept into the other layer.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your native method with `synchronized` prefix to make sure the JNI call is thread-safe. For the cached purpose, you could use global reference or other general cache technique in JNI to cache the value.

Comment: Thanks alijandro. Can you please list few global reference or other general cache techniques in JNI? I am new to this area.

Comment: @KevinOuyang [Here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jni/#notc) describe the global reference cache for method/field id and classes, but you could use this technique in your data cache.